# CSS selector :last-of-type not working if another div is included

Tags: css

This is my HTML

```
<div id="funnel">
    <div class="funnel_column_cont">This is a first div.</div>
    <div class="funnel_column_cont">This is a second div.</div>
    <div class="funnel_column_cont">This is a third div.</div>
    <div class="funnel_column_cont">This is a fourth div.</div>
    <div class="funnel_column_cont">This is a fifth div.</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
#funnel .funnel_column_cont:last-of-type {
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

I want to add background color red to the last div with class "funnel_column_cont". But when `<div class="clr"></div>` is included at the end in the HTML, then my CSS doesn't work.

If I remove this "clr" class div, then `:last-of-type` works as expected. Why? I don't understand because I have mentioned the class `.funnel_column_cont:last-of-type` in CSS. If I add some another HTML element like heading or paragraph, then :last-of-type still works. How to fix it?

Comment: `last-of-type` is looking at the tag, not at the css class (for which there's no direct solution)

Comment: then why :nth-of-type(5) does work?

Answer (score 0):

`last-of-type` pseudo selector can't be applied for class hooks, instead for tags. You can use javascript or, if you know the exact number of elements with that specific class name, you can hook it using `:nth-of-type(5)`